# Copy array from delegate property

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a little problem with a delegate property.

The property "shifts" is a NSMutableArray of objects, initialized and populated by AppDelegate.

```
@interface isaavAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    NSMutableArray *shifts;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *shifts;
```

In a tableview controller, I try to use the data in the array like this:

I declare a new NSMutableArray changePersons:

```
NSMutableArray *changePersons;
```

Then in the viewdidload method:

```
appDelegate = (isaavAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
changePersons = appDelegate.shifts;
```

So I use a NSPredicate to filter the data in the array, but when the changePersons array changes, also appDelegate.shifts changes and I don't understand why...

I tried to copy the array like this:

```
changePersons = [appDelegate.shifts];
```

But when I try to apply the filter with NSPredicate, the App crashes and I get an invalid selector.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks, Marco

Comment: changePersons =[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:appDelegate.shifts];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
changePersons =[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:appDelegate.shifts];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
//in the tableviewcontroller.h

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* changePersons;
```

then

```
//in the .m

self.changePersons = [((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] shifts];
```

Also if you are going to be using the app delegate as above I would recommend for ease of use a #define in your .pch file thus

//.pch file

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#define UIAppDelegate ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])
```

Then the above assignment code would read somewhat neater

```
self.changePersons = [UIAppDelegate shifts];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
changePersons = [appDelegate.shifts mutableCopy];
```

or @Krrish's answer